# Protractor : get element which has not a specific class

Tags: protractor, angularjs-e2e

Im trying to get an e2e test to work on the next example:

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-if="selectedItem">
  <span class-"xxx">This is line 1</span>
  <span class="xxx yyy">This is line 2</span>
</div>
```

**Protractor:**

```
..
element.findByCss('div[ng-if="selectedItem"] span[class!="yyy"]');
..
```

Gives the following error:

> Failed: invalid element state: Failed to execute 'querySelectorAll'
>   on 'Document': 'div[ng-if="selectedItem"] span[class!="yyy"]' is not a
>   valid selector.

The selector works with jQuery though..  I know its not the same. But i cant seem to find how to exclude a class with protractor

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the `not` negation pseudo-class:

```
$('div[ng-if=selectedItem] span:not(.yyy)');
```

Or, in your case, you can also match the complete `class` attribute value:

```
$('div[ng-if=selectedItem] span[class=xxx]');
```

Or, if this is applicable, you can also get the first `span` by index:

```
$$('div[ng-if=selectedItem] span.xxx').first();
```

<sup>`$` here is a shortcut to `element(by.css())`, `$$` - to `element.all(by.css())`</sup>